# Change color intelligent code completion xml android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem at the intelligent code completion, it shows in xml with black background. How can I change the background color?

Comment: Is it a problem with the auto completion display in your IDE ? which IDE are you using ?  please be more specific

Comment: Sorry, IDE Eclipse. In xml, when I trigger the Ctrl + Space, a dialog with the options appear black and I not see anything. I can not send picture if would not be clearer.

Comment: if its a configuration problem maybe this link can help : http://weblog.avp-ptr.de/20120728/how-to-fix-eclipse-colors-for-autocompletion-and-tooltips/